# Creating a Normal Distribution based on Mean and Standard Deviation (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution

I guess this is an easy question, but I have been struggling to solve it. Is it possible to create a Normal Distribution in Matlab purely based on the mean and Standard Deviation? I don't know what the x values are and therefore unable to use the normpdf() function.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gaussian Random Signal with mean 0 and variance 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884945/gaussian-random-signal-with-mean-0-and-variance-1) – how about `normrnd` – it's mentioned in the help and documentation for `normpdf`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `randn` function can do that for you.

The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html) give this example :

> Generate values from a normal distribution with mean 1 and standard
>   deviation 2:
>
> r = 1 + 2.*randn(100,1);